# Pass a string to RGB Colour format

Tags: python, string

I have a dict like this:

```
colour_dict={'Red': '0xFF, 0x00, 0x00','Green':'0x00, 0xFF, 0x00','White':'0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF','Yellow':'0xff, 0xff, 0x00'}
```

I need to pass value of this dict to this code and it works right:

```
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
RGBColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00)
```

When I do below to achieve the same:

```
RGBColor(colour_dict["Red"])
```

It throws me an error as this is a string and this just want in straight number format.

I already tried converting this string to int format but nothing is working.

**Overall  Problem**:

How to pass the value to RGBColor using dict?

Comment: It's not a problem with dictionary. `colour_dict["Red"]` is a *string* `'0xFF, 0x00, 0x00'`, not 3 separate numerical values. Map your dictionary and parse the values into tuples/3-element lists of numerical values.

Comment: @h4z3: I am not saying this is problem with dict, all I am trying to say is how do I solve this problem given it gives with string

Comment: As to converting, remember to pass what base to use: `int('0xFF', base=16)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colour_dict["Red"]` is the **string** `"0xFF, 0x00, 0x00"`, which of course can't be directly converted to an `int`.

You need to convert each piece in the string and pass those values to the `RGBColor` constructor:

```
color = RGBColor(*map(lambda v : int(v, 16), colour_dict["Red"].split(',')))
```

**NOTE:** There's a lot going on in that line, so I'll break it down and explain:

- `colour_dict["Red"].split(',')` extracts the color values substrings: `['0xFF', '0x00', '0x00']`
- `map()` applies the function passed as first argument to each value in the iterable passed as second argument.
- `lambda v : int(v, 16)` converts `v` from hex string to int
- `*` before `map` mans "unpack the values in the iterable that follows". it's a convenient way to pass a list with the RGB values instead of calling `RGBColor(R_val, G_val, B_val)`.

---

#### Python 2 version:

Since python 2 doesn't support the asterisk operator, you need to split the statement in two:

```
r,g,b = map(lambda v : int(v, 16), colour_dict["Red"].split(','))
color = RGBColor(r,g,b)
```

Comment: Or simply change the dict to be `colour_dict={'Red': [0xFF, 0x00, 0x00],...}` and than call `RGBColor(*colour_dict["Red"])`

Comment: Yes, of course changing the input would solve the problem, but the OP specifically asks for a way to pass the colour as a string format

Comment: I wasn't criticizing your answer, I just wanted to point out that changing the input will make more readable code.

Comment: @orangeInk I agree, but it's possible the dict is just given in that format (e.g., the values are loaded from a file), so I normally assume changing the input format is not a possible solution :)

Comment: @GPhilo: Can you also give a Python 2.7 corresponding answer to this ...as `*` operator shows an error!!

Comment: For `Python 2.7` it says `Invalid Syntax`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
RGBColor(colour_dict["Red"])
```

by

```
eval("RGBColor({})".format(colour_dict["Red"]))
```

Comment: Using `eval` should always be avoided if there's a viable alternative

Answer (score 0):

I find the [`map lambda answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56325980/7916438) a bit overkill, here is a less fancy variant:

```
color = RGBColor(*[int(x,16) for x in colour_dict["Red"].split(",")])
```

Answer (score 0):

colour_dict["Red"] is a string, not three numbers

you can do like this:

```
a = list(colour_dict["Red"])
RGBColor(int(a[0]), int(a[2]), int(a[4]))
```

**a:['0xFF', ',', '0x00', ',', '0x00'], has 5 characters in total**